# Find an exact length match in a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

How can I match the string which starts with C88 and ends with 03D using regex in Python from the text below:

```
0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE
4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :C88C87D325BFC86211ED38A05F04F90A92F252E9D6E5425D54F1B27F3888F95B123BFBB634864DEDF0A6B8636830B6AB70011C6B4C6D8368BCD6FC72D1C341B97130737F0BA520D4C44982EA4554AE19CD54F21DA48ECF634C38E3586253FFC815633510FA4FA8B7B1E07E4E2EABF48603EDFB2E53DFA6CC1F894F892B742B84A2CEA29837B1047D7CC401365B3091B6C7DED09CD3BFECD8EAF66F198A80B27DB9DB334CAE200410AE984D3CE413D8BA04833AB5CE7B7FA43CC848143F82B542343D537E4C79DB30FDFDB66B01259CACE9C3D430A38574F3A09278DD4263CACB8A12175CE7A082FBA63A565F31CBA2176C710008C1781E50C5270FE18142B03D
265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

As it is clearly seen, there are also some whitespace between the string and the keyword 'INTEGER'. If needed, we know the exact length of the match which is 512 characters.

Comment: `C88\w{506}03D` isn't enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.search`.

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE
4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :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
265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001"""

m = re.search("(prim\: INTEGER\s+\:(?P<uuid>[A-Z0-9]{512}))", s)
if m:
    print m.group('uuid')
```

**Output:**

```
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
```

Comment: Thanks, it works quite well :-)

Comment: You are Welcome :)